# How to prevent Reflected XSS for java Object

Tags: java, xss

I scanned my project in Checkmarx and its showing as Reflected XSS for an java object which is a parameter in the method below is the reported error by checkmarx:

Method readDataUsingQueryObject at line 743 of
/src/main/java/com/cognizant/hap/core/controller/DataController.java gets user input for the query element.
This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is
eventually displayed to the user in method readDataUsingQueryObject at line 743 of
/src/main/java/com/cognizant/hap/core/controller/DataController.java. This may enable a Cross-Site-Scripting
attack.

Below is the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/readGraph/{iLakeId}/{dataPoolName}/{dataspaceName}/{datasetName}" }, headers = "Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<DataLakeGraph> readGraph(
            @ApiParam(name = "iLakeId", value = "int", required = true) @PathVariable int iLakeId,
            @ApiParam(name = "dataPoolName", value = "Datapool name", required = true) @PathVariable String dataPoolName,
            @ApiParam(name = "dataspaceName", value = "Dataspace name", required = true) @PathVariable String dataspaceName,
            @ApiParam(name = "datasetName", value = "Graph Dataset name", required = true) @PathVariable String datasetName,
            @ApiParam(name = "query", value = "Query model", required = true) @RequestBody(required = false) Query query,
            HttpServletResponse servRes) {
      DataLakeGraph dataLake = iLakeService.readGraph(iLakeId,
                    dataPoolName, dataspaceName, datasetName, query);
            return HAPUtil.createResponseEntity(dataLake, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Below is the Class:

```
public class Query {

    private int size;
    private int offset;
    private String queryString;
    private List<Field> select;
    private List<Filter> filters;
    private String filterString;
    private SortOn sortOn;
    private List<Aggregation> aggregations;
    private Histogram histogram;
    private GraphQuery graphQuery;
    private boolean highlight;

   //setters and getters
}
```

Can you please let me know how to sanitized or validated the Query object which is a parameter in the method?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which lines of the code you included in your query call line 743 of DataController.java.   The SAST Checkmarx tool found a path where the query from the user is sent back in the response, but it's not in the code snippets you've posted.  In general for reflected cross-site scripting, you should do positive or whitelist validation (e.g. accept known good) of any user input that can be later sent back to the user.  The user query should be a well-known schema so this should be possible.

Here's an example of complete whitelist validation of user input,  followed by exact match (or roster) validation.   In this case this is checking that the user input is one of the 13 states of the country of Malaysia.  mState is the user input.

```
private static final String stateFormatMy = "^[A-Z]{3}$";  // three upppercase alpha characters   
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(stateFormatMy);  
public boolean validateStateMy()
{   
    // always check the length of any string before you do any regex operations
    // to protect against ReDoS 
    if(mState.length() != 3)
    {
        System.err.println("State abbreviations in Malaysia are three characters");
        return false;  
    }

    // Whtelist validation ensures three uppercase alpha characters 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mState);
    if(!matcher.matches())
    {
        System.err.println("State abbreviations in Malaysia are three uppercase alpha characters");
        return false;  
    }

    // Exact match or roster validation    
    boolean bValid = true; 
    switch(mState)
    {
    case "JHR": break; 
    case "KDH": break;
    case "KTN": break;
    case "MLK": break;
    case "NSN": break;
    case "PHG": break;
    case "PLS": break;
    case "PRK": break;
    case "PNG": break;
    case "SBH": break;
    case "SWK": break;
    case "SGR": break;
    case "TRG": break;
    default:
        System.err.println("The abbreviation does not indicate a state (according to Wikipedia)");
        bValid = false; 
        break;  
    }
    return bValid ;
```